# Regarding formatting of the query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have made an application in which I have put the sql queries in java method as below..

```
private static String getSaleTransactionsQuery(final String currentTradingDate){

        final String query =
            " SELECT '990' line_code, " +
            " sum(toti_wag.TTIW_CUST_CNT) amount " +
            " FROM total_till_wag toti_wag " +
            " where toti_wag.TOTI_TRADING_DATE = '" + currentTradingDate + "' ";

        return query;
    }
```

Now when I want to filter out sql queries then I have to copy this query on the sql file and have to manually remove the quotes("") and the plus(+) sign in order to make them as pure sql and then have to execute them to see the query output , is there any other tool which will format all these means remove the quotes and the plus sign ,please advise

Comment: Duh! Everything cannot be straightforward. However, why don't you convert your code into single line sql, i.e. `final String query = "SELECT '990' line_code, sum(toti_wag.TTIW_CUST_CNT) amount FROM total_till_wag toti_wag where toti_wag.TOTI_TRADING_DATE = '" + currentTradingDate + "' ";`. I doubt there would be any tool to do this.

Comment: @gotuskar..thanks but I thought if there is then please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a simple script to help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/GFhFg/7/

I found it pretty easy to throw something together in JavaScript that does the job.

```
function cleanIt(txt) {
    var result = "";
    // remove semi-colon at the end
    txt = txt.replace(/\;$/m, '');
    var lines = txt.split('\n');
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        // trim whitespace
        line = line.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
        // remove + from beginning or end of line
        line = line.replace(/^\+\s*/, '').replace(/\s*\+$/, '');
        // remove quotes
        line = line.replace(/"/g, '');
        // remove the +'s around parameters/variables
        line = line.replace(/('?\s*\+\s*)([^\s\+']+)(\s*\+\s*'?)/g, '$2')
        result += line + '\n';
    }
    return result;
}
```

Obviously it hasn't be exhaustively tested, but it should give you a base to start from.

Comment: @LastCoder..Amazing discovery Man..!! Really grateful to You, Thanks a lot..!!

Answer (score 0):

**There is no automated way.**  You may write some generic custom function to do it for you.

One good proactive is to log the required details in log files. If you do and log your query then you will see your query without quotes and plus signs in the log file.